# How are values passed onto new variables from a main function to another function without using the same variable names?

Tags: c, function, variables, parameter-passing

[This is the code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryQTz.png)

I'm new to coding so please bear with me.

I'm currently trying to understand the flow and interplay between functions. I understand the basics of how we can call functions, pass arguments between and get return values etc.

However in deconstructing a solution to a practice problem to calculate splitting a bill, asking for user input in form of floats in the main function, these float variables are named

```
bill_amount
tax_percent
tip_percent
```

Inside the function to calculate the bill and split it we are using other float variables named

```
bill
tax
tip
```

While running the debugger to understand what's going on I can see how these variabels used in the "calculate" function are assigned the values of the variables `bill_amount`, `tax_amount` and `tip_percent` which we get via user input in the main function.

So my question is:

How does C know to pass the values from the variables in our main function to the calculate function? For example the value in `tax_percent` getting passed to variable `tax`, without specifically instructing the program to do so?

The program works just fine, I've tried googling to understand how this works and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you please show the code in question?

Comment: Parameters are passed in order.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the code to the post! 

So Im basically trying to understand how the values in the int main function gets passed to the variabels in the "half" function seeing how the names are different and were not instructing to program to pass the values on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assignment like `x = a;` is an instruction to set `x` to the value of `a`.

Given a function defined as `void foo(int x, int y);`, a function call like `foo(a, b);` is an instruction to:

- Start executing `foo`.
- Set the `x` of `foo` to the value of `a`.
- Set the `y` of `foo` to the value of `b`.
- Continue executing `foo`.

In a typical C implementation, the way this is done is:

- When `foo(a, b)` is evaluated, the values of `a` and `b` are stored in places designated for passing arguments to functions, typically certain CPU registers or certain places on the hardware stack.
- Where the machine instructions the compiler generates for the `foo` function need the values of `x` and `y`, they get them from the places the values of the arguments were put.

Answer (score 0):

> How does C know to pass the values from the variables in our main function to the calculate function? For example the value in "tax_percent" getting passed to variable "tax", without specifically instructing the program to do so?

By order. The name is irrelevant - the first parameter gets passed to the first parameter, etc.

So for example, this declaration:

```
int func(int, double, char);
```

matches this function definition:

```
int func(int units, double weight_per_unit, char price_set)
{
```

If you want to look further into how it works under the hood (e.g. what actually happens in memory and registers when this code runs) the search term you're looking for is "calling convention," and the wikipedia page isn't a half bad place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions